# Integers N congruent to 5 mod 23 and to 6 mod 223

Tags: number-theory

2236 is an example of number congruent to 5 $\pmod {23} $ and to 6 $\pmod {223}$. How can I find a list of numbers N congruent to $5\pmod {23}$ and to $6 \pmod {223}$? Is this list infinite?

Comment: Please take a look at the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  If you study that, you'll learn how to approach problems like this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You have found one number yourself, $2236$.

That's the difficult part done since you can now just add any multiple of $23\times223$ to this number to obtain infinitely many further numbers.

Comment: Or subtract any multiple of $23\times223$. And those are *the only* integers that work. And OP might enjoy trying to prove all these statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$N=5+23x\\N=6+223y$$ With your solution $(x_0,y_0)$ or any other particular solution of $23x-223y=1$ you do have
$$23x-223y=1\\23x_0-223y_0=1$$ so you have $$23(x-x_0)-223(y-y_0)=0$$ from which you get the infinity of integer solutions with parameter $t$
$$x-x_0=223t\\y-y_0=23t$$